# One program changing the data of another

Tags: c, windows, ipc

Can I write and run a program that creates an integer, say a and can I write ANOTHER program to modify this integer while both are running?

Comment: Yes, though shared memory or some IPC notification mechanism probably. Can you tell us more about the environment these programs would run in (Windows? Linux? embedded? same PC, remote?) so we can give you more specific advice?

Comment: Yes, if you put that integer in _shared memory_ accessible by _ANOTHER_ program.

Comment: Windows. I am basically trying to write a program to illustrate the use of volatile.

Comment: Right. You might find it simplest to use two threads in the one process I'd think.

Comment: ATaylor: At least my operating system has memory protection.

Comment: @Rohan could you please give me a simple C program for doing that, if its indeed simple?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you're going to have to involve some kind of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). On most modern operating systems, memory is virtual and raw pointers cannot be directly shared.